# jQuery get fakepath for file input with "multiple" attribute to preview image

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, filereader

I have input file (Multiple) use to upload images. When an image is uploaded it will display as a thumbnail and also as a full view. I already have `URL.createObjectURL()` that renders the image into `blob` but when the number of images is more then it is effecting the page a little since each image is having 2 blob-data for thumbnail and full view.

For single file upload it was easy to have `URL.createObjectURL()` for thumbnails and `$(this).val()` to generate fake path for full view. But I do not know how to do that with multi file upload.

Sample code:

```
$('#imageBtn').on('change', function(){
    var inputFiles = this.files;
    $(inputFiles).each(function(index) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
       reader.onloadend = function(){
           RenderedPath = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
           FakePath = inputFile.val();
           // Some codes to populate the thumbnail and fullview
       }
    });
});
```

So, how can I obtain the fake path for each uploaded image?

Comment: What do you want to do with this fakePath? Being a "fake" path it is normally of no use, moreover since the File API came out, and that each File object has its own `name` property.

Comment: @Kaiido fake path is good enough to display the image which will reduce the load.

Comment: @sam no, fakepath is of **no use**, at all. I'll try to post a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, sorry for being lame. i am new to scripting side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what you want to do with this fakePath. Being a "*fake*" path, it's of no use.

Historically, (before the File API), it was a way to retrieve the name of a selected File, but now that we've got the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), this information is provided inside the File object directly.

So if you really want to build it yourself, like in the case of an `input[type=file][multiple]`, then you can simply prepend `"C:\fakePath\"` to the File's `name`.

But once again, **you won't be able to do anything from this string.**

Also note that in your code you don't do anything with the FileReader's result, and anyway, you don't need it at this point, so remove it here, since it is probably one of the causes of your memory issues.
Indeed, BlobURIs in the case of user-provided Files won't use any memory, being simple pointers to the file stored on user-disk, while reading it as a dataURI will actually load the whole data three times in memory.

So for the part you shown, it can simply be

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  var files = this.files;
  $(files).each(function(index, file) {
    // Still don't know why you want this...
    var fakepath = 'C:\\fakepath\\';
    $('body').append('<div>' +
      // build  a fake path string for each File
      '<p class="path">'+ fakepath + file.name + '</p>' +
      // all that is really needed to display the image
      '<img src="'+URL.createObjectURL(file)+'">' +
     '</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Now, you stated in a comment that you need the FileReader to pass it to jsZip library, if you are talking about [this one](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), then you've to know that [it accepts Blobs](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_data.html). So you still don't need a FileReader.

```js
var fileList = [];
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  var files = this.files;
  $(files).each(function(index, file) {
    $('body').append($('<img>', {
      src: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      onload: function() { fileList.push(file); $('button').attr('disabled', false);},
      onerror: function() { $(this).remove(); }
    }));
  });
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  fileList.forEach(function(file) {
    zip.file(file.name, file);
  });
  zip.generateAsync({
      type: "blob"
    })
    .then(function(blob) {
      saveAs(blob, "myfiles.zip");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*">
<button disabled>save as zip</button>
```

Comment: i tried to prepend "C:\fakePath\" to the File's name but the image didnt show. can you provide a link for the File API please? if jszip accepts blob then you are right i dont need filereader. thanks for the info mate.

Comment: @sam I added an example generating the zip file, and a link to MDN's article about the File API, which is quite a vast API.